# Loading videos with XMLHttpRequest on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, video, xmlhttprequest, video.js

I'm using video.js to play application/x-mpegURL videos on my site.

I need all the video related requests (e.g. to m3u8 file) to go through the XMLHttpRequest object, as I'm adding functionality at that point.

It all works fine on Chrome for PC for example, but when I move to mobile (using Chrome android emulation) the requests don't go through the XHR object at all, for some obscure reason. In the network tab it says that the request's initiator is simply "Other".

Any idea what's the reason for that behavior and how can I circumvent that?

Answer (score -1):

After a bit of research and trial and error I figured the entire question is probably just wrong.
As far as I understand, the mobile browser has native support for HLS video therefore you have no control over the video download.
When using video.js for instance with the HLS plugin on a PC, it uses XMLHttpRequest to add support for such videos on devices that do not natively support it.